# How to clean the database, dropping all records using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy. I want to delete all the records efficiently present in database but I don't want to drop the table/database.

I tried with the following code:

```
con = engine.connect()
trans = con.begin()

con.execute(table.delete())
trans.commit()
```

It seems, it is not a very efficient one since I am iterating over all tables present in the database.
Can someone suggest a better and more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: For some databases exists 'truncate' statement. It recreates table and works faster and not transactional. You can execute it with raw SQL with engine.execute('''truncate tablename''')

Comment: @Varela Thanks for sharing your thoughts I want to write the method/function in such a way that it should work on all databases. Since `truncate` is DB dependent, it wouldn't be my first choice.

Comment: Then there is nothing better, you cannot omit iterating through tables and delete probably the only statement that works for all DBs.

Comment: What is wrong with `metadata.drop_all()` then `metadata.create_all()`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763472/sqlalchemy-clear-database-content-but-dont-drop-the-schema/25220958#25220958

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you models rely on the existing DB schema (usually use `autoload=True`), you cannot avoid deleting data in each table. [`MetaData.sorted_tables`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns) comes in handy:

```
for tbl in reversed(meta.sorted_tables):
    engine.execute(tbl.delete())
```

If your models do define the complete schema, there is nothing simpler than [`drop_all`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.drop_all)/[`create_all`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all) (as already pointed out by @jadkik94).

*Further, `TRUNCATE` would anyways not work on the tables which are referenced by [`ForeignKeys`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey), which is limiting the usage significantly.*

Comment: Hi. my `meta.tables` or `meta.sorted_tables` is an empty list for some reason. I have `meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=engine)`. Why does it show empty while database has tables?

Comment: If you have no models defined bound to this `meta`, there would not be anything. But if you do not want to define models, and would like to `reflect` them from the database, you need to call [`MetaData.reflect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect) first

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help! Just one more question, if you don't mind. Now to get the table instance I can do `meta.tables['tasks']`, but that means that I have to remember the class name (`Tasks`) and the table name 'tasks'. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: I am not sure you are approaching this from the right angle. But please take a look at [Using Reflection with Declarative](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html#using-reflection-with-declarative) and [Declarative Reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/examples.html#declarative-reflection) example. These should give you an idea how to have only model classes defined without tables.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. What I needed was `session.query(Tasks).delete()`

Answer (score 10):

For me putting `tbl.drop(engine)` worked, but not `engine.execute(tbl.delete())`

SQLAlchemy 0.8.0b2 and 
Python 2.7.3

Comment: Same here. Although that _does_ drop the tables instead of clearing them.