# SQLAlchemy Joining a Session into an External Transaction Not Working as Expected

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on rewriting the test suite for a large application using `pytest` and looking to have isolation between each test function. What I've noticed is, multiple calls to `commit` inside a SAVEPOINT are causing records to be entered into the DB. I've distilled out as much code as possible for the following example:

****init**.py**

```py
# Create the SQLAlchemy db instance
db: SQLAlchemy = SQLAlchemy(
    engine_options={"connect_args": {"options": "-c timezone=utc"}}
)
# Initialize Marshmallow
ma: Marshmallow = Marshmallow()

unleash = Unleash()

def create_app(config=None):
    # Create the Flask app
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Flask is not autoloading FLASK_ENV anymore
    app.config.from_object("app.config.Testing")
    if not database_exists(app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]):
        create_database(app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"])

    # initialize DB
    db.init_app(app)
    # Initialize Marshmallow
    ma.init_app(app)


    with app.app_context():
        # import models and setup blueprints
        ...
```

**conftest.py**

```py
import os

import pytest
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import db_data
from app import create_app
from app import db as _db


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app():
    """
    Returns session-wide application.
    """
    os.environ["FLASK_ENV"] = "testing"
    return create_app()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db(app: Flask, request):
    """
    Returns session-wide initialised database.
    """
    with app.app_context():
        _db.drop_all()
        _db.create_all()

        db_data.initialize_common_data(_db, app.logger)
        db_data.create_test_users(_db, app.logger)
        db_data.initialize_functional_test_data(_db, app.logger)

        yield _db

@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def session(app: Flask, db: SQLAlchemy):
    """
    Returns function-scoped session.
    """
    # from https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html
    with app.app_context():
        connection = db.engine.connect()

        # begin a non-ORM transaction
        trans = connection.begin()

        # bind an individual Session to the connection
        sess = Session(bind=connection)

        # start the session in a SAVEPOINT...
        sess.begin_nested()

        # then each time that SAVEPOINT ends, reopen it
        @event.listens_for(sess, "after_transaction_end")
        def restart_savepoint(s, t):
            if t.nested and (t._parent is None or not t._parent.nested):
                s.expire_all()
                s.begin_nested()

        yield sess

        ### Cleanup ##
        # rollback - everything that happened with the Session above
        # (including calls to commit()) is rolled back.
        sess.close()
        trans.rollback()

        # return connection to the Engine
        connection.close()
```

**conftestv2.py**

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def session(app: Flask, db: SQLAlchemy):
    """
    Returns function-scoped session.
    """
    # from https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html
    with app.app_context():
        connection = db.engine.connect()

        # begin a non-ORM transaction
        trans = connection.begin()

        # start the session in a SAVEPOINT...
        db.session.begin_nested()

        # then each time that SAVEPOINT ends, reopen it
        @event.listens_for(db.session, "after_transaction_end")
        def restart_savepoint(s, t):
            if t.nested and (t._parent is None or not t._parent.nested):
                s.expire_all()
                s.begin_nested()

        # yield sess
        yield db.session

        ### Cleanup ##
        # rollback - everything that happened with the Session above
        # (including calls to commit()) is rolled back.
        db.session.close()
        trans.rollback()

        # return connection to the Engine
        connection.close()
```

**test_user.py**

```py
from app.user.models import User
from app import db as _db

def test_list_trackers():
    print("SESSSS:", _db.session)
    _db.session.add(User(email="aaa@aaa.aaa"))
    _db.session.commit()

    _db.session.add(User(email="aaa@aaa.aaab"))
    _db.session.commit()
```

I've tried to use this as a guideline: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites

And have looked at the following resources (among many others):

- [Rollback Many Transactions between tests in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224624/rollback-many-transactions-between-tests-in-flask)
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.SessionEvents.after_transaction_create
- https://github.com/jeancochrane/pytest-flask-sqlalchemy/issues/28

Relevant packages, and versions, I have installed:

```sh
$ pip list
Package                           Version
--------------------------------- ---------
coverage                          6.3.1
Faker                             12.1.0
Flask                             1.1.2
Flask-Cors                        3.0.10
Flask-Environments                0.1
Flask-HTTPAuth                    4.2.0
flask-marshmallow                 0.11.0
Flask-Migrate                     2.7.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy                  2.5.1
psycopg2-binary                   2.8.6
pytest                            6.2.3
pytest-cov                        3.0.0
SQLAlchemy                        1.3.18
SQLAlchemy-Paginator              0.2
sqlalchemy-stubs                  0.3
SQLAlchemy-Utils                  0.38.2
timezonefinder                    5.2
```

Database is running in `docker-compose` using the `postgres 12.2-alpine` image.

Comment: Updated to add conftestv2.py. I was able to take a step forward with this change, but some more complicated tests with much more logic in them are failing. At this point I'm not sure if the fixtures are working incorrectly or the application isn't using sessions properly.

Comment: Continuing my investigation it seems like tests are impacting one another, so maybe there is still something wrong in the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of SQLAlchemy's Gitter community I was able to solve this. There were two issues that needed solving:

1. The `after_transaction_end` event was being registered for each individual test but not removed after the test ended. Because of this multiple events were being invoked between each test.
2. The `_db` being yielded from the `db` fixture was inside the app context, which it shouldn't have been.

Updated `conftest.py`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db(app: Flask, request):
    """
    Returns session-wide initialised database.
    """
    with app.app_context():
        _db.drop_all()
        _db.create_all()

        db_data.initialize_common_data(_db, app.logger)
        db_data.create_test_users(_db, app.logger)
        db_data.initialize_functional_test_data(_db, app.logger)

        _db.session.close_all()

    yield _db


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def session(app: Flask, db: SQLAlchemy):
    """
    Returns function-scoped session.
    """
    # from https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html
    with app.app_context():
        connection = db.engine.connect()

        # begin a non-ORM transaction
        trans = connection.begin()

        # start the session in a SAVEPOINT...
        db.session.begin_nested()

        # then each time that SAVEPOINT ends, reopen it
        @event.listens_for(db.session, "after_transaction_end")
        def restart_savepoint(s, t):
            if t.nested and (t._parent is not None and not t._parent.nested):
                s.expire_all()
                s.begin_nested()

        # yield sess
        yield db.session

        ### Cleanup ##
        # rollback - everything that happened with the Session above
        # (including calls to commit()) is rolled back.
        event.remove(db.session, "after_transaction_end", restart_savepoint)

        db.session.close_all()
        trans.rollback()

        # return connection to the Engine
        connection.close()
```